# Redirect to mobile version with sub domain

Tags: seo, redirects, mobile

I know redirect a website to mobile version such `example.com` to `m.example.com` is the best after `responsive` design but my question is while the desktop `URL` is `example.com/index.aspx` and want to redirect to mobile version `example.com/index_m.aspx`. or `example.com/car.aspx` to `example.com/car_m.aspx`. And `html` and `css` totally different with desktop version.

### Goal:

With a function i detect `user-agent` and want to redirect from `example.com/gallery.aspx` to `example.com/gallery_m.aspx` if device is `mobile` or etc.

### The questions:

1. Is this good method at all? or harmful for `SEO` or `google index`?
2. If it's okay, which redirect i should use? `301` or `302`
3. Should i use `canonical` tag?

Comment: Actually [responsive design](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design) `is a setup where the server always sends the same HTML code to all devices and CSS is used to alter the rendering of the page on the device`, thus redirection isn't required. If you're going to separate the URLs of your desktop and mobile sites, you'll need to provide a [signal to Google](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls) with a `<link> tag with rel="canonical" and rel="alternate" elements`. `302` redirects are recommended for this purpose.